# Why such loop does not catch error when inputting a string?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, boost

```
    int SelectedIndex;         
   int i = 4;
      while(SelectedIndex > i-1 || SelectedIndex < 0)
      {
       try{
       std::cout <<"please input index from 0 to " << i-1 << std::endl;
       std::cin >> SelectedIndex;
       }
       catch(std::exception& e){SelectedIndex = 999;}
      }
```

Why such loop does not catch error when inputting a string?
How to fix it? I can use std::string and Boost library and reg exp.

Comment: 1. SelectIndex is not initialized. 2. Can you explain what you want to happen, and what actually happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming are trying to read in an integer using `std::cin` and detect if the user input a string instead:

If the user does input a string, an exception will *not* be thrown (which is why your code doesn't work as expected). Instead, the input will be left in the buffer, and `cin` will be in an error state. The next `cin >>` will read the same value from the buffer in an endless loop, unless you clear the error state and buffer before the next iteration.

See [this article](http://www.augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/tutorial/iotips.html#directly) which explains exactly how to read in an integer (and what happens when a string is input instead) as well as how to clear the error state and buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The stream library doesn't throw exceptions by default. You have to enable it first like in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int number;
    std::cin.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit | std::ios::eofbit);
    std::cout << "enter a number: ";
    try
    {
        std::cin >> number;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

Comment: It dies... (vs brings mr to some strange C++ file)